# Cannot convert AAssetManager to jobject

Tags: android, android-ndk

I paste the code in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Android_GLUT_Wrapper#Accessing_assets in my android_main and I got error :

> cannot convert 'AAssetManager*' to 'jobject {aka _jobject*}' in initialization

from line: 
    `jobject assetManager = app->activity->assetManager;`

Can anyone explained what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AAssetManager` is a C struct, so the the pointer is not assignable to a `jobject`.

The code you copied is explaining how to get the `AAssetManager` pointer, and clearly you already have it! I suspect you don't actually need this line at all, just use `app->activity->assetManager`.

```
AAssetManager *mgr = state_param->activity->assetManager;
```

Comment: Looking at native_activity.h, I think the example is wrong.  Should just be `AAssetManager* mgr = state_param->activity->assetManager;`.

Comment: Yeah, based on the error message you are getting, that should work.

Comment: from where do i get state_param ??

Comment: @AmitHooda check out the sample linked in the question

Comment: @krsteeve It uses it without initialization